# TextBox does not detect input

Tags: c#, textbox, dataset

I have a listbox binded to a table "Leave" in a dataset and two textboxes for user to enter the name of leave and the number of days. Basically, the user is able to select an item from the listbox and its information will display in the two textboxes (I already have done this) and user can edit the two fields.

My Edit Code:

```
string expression = "Name = '" + currentLeaveNameSelected + "'";
DataRow[] selectRow = leaveHolDs.Tables[0].Select(expression);

try
{
   selectRow[0]["NumberOfDays"] = int.Parse(LeaveDaysTxtBox.Text);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
   selectRow[0]["NumberOfDays"] = -1;
}

selectRow[0]["Name"] = LeaveNameTxtBox.Text;
```

currentLeaveNameSelected is the original Leave name stored in the dataset. However when I run this code, I can edit the number of days but not the Leave Name. But when switch the order to

```
string expression = "Name = '" + currentLeaveNameSelected + "'";
DataRow[] selectRow = leaveHolDs.Tables[0].Select(expression);

selectRow[0]["Name"] = LeaveNameTxtBox.Text;

try
{
   selectRow[0]["NumberOfDays"] = int.Parse(LeaveDaysTxtBox.Text);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
   selectRow[0]["NumberOfDays"] = -1;
}
```

It becomes I only can edit the Leave Name but not the number of days, as in the changes for the Number of Days does not change despite changing the textbox field. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: No. I did not use IsPostBack. I do not have any codes inside Page_Load, I using windows forms so obly have the form1() { initializecomponent() and some of my functions}

Comment: @Rahul Erm, Basically the dataset is not updating the Number of Days field and only updating the Name if I put the changing Name operation in front of the Number of Days and vice versa.

Comment: Does it change something when getting hold on the DataRow once and for all DataRow selectRow = leaveHolDs.Tables[0].Select(expression)[0]; and then only manipulating it (selectRow instead of selectRow[0])
Also, please post code where do you perform your AcceptChanges - Update